# polars use Expression API with DataFrame's rows

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I am a new `polars` user and I want to apply a function in every `polars DataFrame` row. In `pandas` I would use the `apply` function specifying that the input of the function is the `DataFrame`'s row instead of the `DataFrame`'s column(s).

I saw the `apply` function of polars library, and it says that it is preferable, because it is much more efficient, to use the Expression API instead of the `apply` function on a polars `DataFrame`. The documentation has examples of the Expression API with the `select` function, but `select` is used with the `DataFrames`'s columns. Is there a way to use the  Expression API with the rows of the `DataFrame`?

**Edit for providing an example**

I have a `DataFrame` with this structure

```
l=[(1,2,3,4,22,23,None,None),(5,6,8,10,None,None,None,None)]
df=pl.DataFrame(data=l, orient='row')
```

i.e. a `DataFrame` that at some point and until the end, a row has `None` values. In this example, in the first row the `None` values start at column 6, while in the second, the `None` values start at column 4.

What I want to do is to find the most efficient polars way to turn this `DataFrame` into a `DataFrame` with only three columns, where the first column is the first element of the row, the second column is the second element of the row, and the third will have as a list all the other elements of the following columns that are not `None`.

Comment: Can you show an actual example of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the column names, you can:

- select the first 2 columns by name
- [create a list](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/expressions/lists/#functions) from all columns [excluding](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.exclude.html#polars-exclude) the 2 named columns
- remove nulls from the list with [`.arr.eval`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.arr.eval.html#polars.Expr.arr.eval)

```
df.select(
   pl.col("column_0", "column_1"), 
   pl.concat_list(pl.exclude("column_0", "column_1"))
     .arr.eval(pl.element().drop_nulls())
)
```

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────────┐
│ column_0 ┆ column_1 ┆ column_2     │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---          │
│ i64      ┆ i64      ┆ list[i64]    │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════════╡
│ 1        ┆ 2        ┆ [3, 4, … 23] │
│ 5        ┆ 6        ┆ [8, 10]      │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────────┘
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for. Your sources are very good. Thank you for that, too.